# Ubuntu Live USB cannot see any hard drive partitions

Tags: system-installation, dell, boot-repair, xps

I recently purchased a Dell XPS 9570. I've spent the majority of the day trying to install Ubuntu on it to dual boot with Windows. After having some issues with getting Nvidia graphics card drivers to work, I decided to delete the Ubuntu partition and try to reinstall. But now when I try to install, it only shows "/dev/sda" in the possible places to install. Windows still boots normally after changing the boot sequence to prioritze Windows over grub. I tried running boot-repair from the live cd, and this is the output:

```
Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sda1 busy

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT16
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda2 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda2 starts at sector 3138412. According to the info 
                       in the boot sector, sda2 has 0 sectors.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sda1 busy
mount: /dev/sda2 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sda2 busy

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 14.4 GiB, 15502147584 bytes, 30277632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *              0     3,172,287     3,172,288   0 Empty
/dev/sda2           3,138,412     3,143,147         4,736  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

/dev/sda1 overlaps with /dev/sda2

GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1   +  R              0     3,172,231     3,172,232 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda2   +  R      3,138,412     3,143,147         4,736 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        2018-02-28-19-15-18-00                 iso9660    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS amd64
/dev/sda2        B51F-26E1                              vfat       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun  7 23:08 usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_60A44C413C4EBFA099840043-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  7 23:08 usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_60A44C413C4EBFA099840043-0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  7 23:08 usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_60A44C413C4EBFA099840043-0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sda

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f1 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 00  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  5a 51 b4 08 cd 13 83 e1  3f 5b 51 0f b6 c6 40 50  |ZQ......?[Q...@P|
00000080  f7 e1 53 52 50 bb 00 7c  b9 04 00 66 a1 b0 07 e8  |..SRP..|...f....|
00000090  44 00 0f 82 80 00 66 40  80 c7 02 e2 f2 66 81 3e  |D.....f@.....f.>|
000000a0  40 7c fb c0 78 70 75 09  fa bc ec 7b ea 44 7c 00  |@|..xpu....{.D|.|
000000b0  00 e8 83 00 69 73 6f 6c  69 6e 75 78 2e 62 69 6e  |....isolinux.bin|
000000c0  20 6d 69 73 73 69 6e 67  20 6f 72 20 63 6f 72 72  | missing or corr|
000000d0  75 70 74 2e 0d 0a 66 60  66 31 d2 66 03 06 f8 7b  |upt...f`f1.f...{|
000000e0  66 13 16 fc 7b 66 52 66  50 06 53 6a 01 6a 10 89  |f...{fRfP.Sj.j..|
000000f0  e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b c0 e4  06 88 e1 88 c5 92 f6 36  |.f.6.{.........6|
00000100  ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1 41 b8  01 02 8a 16 f2 7b cd 13  |.{....A......{..|
00000110  8d 64 10 66 61 c3 e8 1e  00 4f 70 65 72 61 74 69  |.d.fa....Operati|
00000120  6e 67 20 73 79 73 74 65  6d 20 6c 6f 61 64 20 65  |ng system load e|
00000130  72 72 6f 72 2e 0d 0a 5e  ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62 04 b3  |rror...^....>b..|
00000140  07 cd 10 3c 0a 75 f1 cd  18 f4 eb fd 00 00 00 00  |...<.u..........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  5c 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  26 2a 0f 55 00 00 80 00  |\.......&*.U....|
000001c0  01 00 00 60 e0 fd 00 00  00 00 c0 67 30 00 00 fe  |...`.......g0...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff 6c e3  2f 00 80 12 00 00 00 00  |......l./.......|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


/dev/sda1: unknown GPT attributes
1000000000000001

/dev/sda2: unknown GPT attributes
1000000000000001
Unknown BootLoader on sda1

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f1 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 00  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  5a 51 b4 08 cd 13 83 e1  3f 5b 51 0f b6 c6 40 50  |ZQ......?[Q...@P|
00000080  f7 e1 53 52 50 bb 00 7c  b9 04 00 66 a1 b0 07 e8  |..SRP..|...f....|
00000090  44 00 0f 82 80 00 66 40  80 c7 02 e2 f2 66 81 3e  |D.....f@.....f.>|
000000a0  40 7c fb c0 78 70 75 09  fa bc ec 7b ea 44 7c 00  |@|..xpu....{.D|.|
000000b0  00 e8 83 00 69 73 6f 6c  69 6e 75 78 2e 62 69 6e  |....isolinux.bin|
000000c0  20 6d 69 73 73 69 6e 67  20 6f 72 20 63 6f 72 72  | missing or corr|
000000d0  75 70 74 2e 0d 0a 66 60  66 31 d2 66 03 06 f8 7b  |upt...f`f1.f...{|
000000e0  66 13 16 fc 7b 66 52 66  50 06 53 6a 01 6a 10 89  |f...{fRfP.Sj.j..|
000000f0  e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b c0 e4  06 88 e1 88 c5 92 f6 36  |.f.6.{.........6|
00000100  ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1 41 b8  01 02 8a 16 f2 7b cd 13  |.{....A......{..|
00000110  8d 64 10 66 61 c3 e8 1e  00 4f 70 65 72 61 74 69  |.d.fa....Operati|
00000120  6e 67 20 73 79 73 74 65  6d 20 6c 6f 61 64 20 65  |ng system load e|
00000130  72 72 6f 72 2e 0d 0a 5e  ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62 04 b3  |rror...^....>b..|
00000140  07 cd 10 3c 0a 75 f1 cd  18 f4 eb fd 00 00 00 00  |...<.u..........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  5c 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  26 2a 0f 55 00 00 80 00  |\.......&*.U....|
000001c0  01 00 00 60 e0 fd 00 00  00 00 c0 67 30 00 00 fe  |...`.......g0...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff 6c e3  2f 00 80 12 00 00 00 00  |......l./.......|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 9 (/proc/15543/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 20305: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[46554]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 20305: bash

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20180607_2307 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa65
boot-sav version : 4ppa65
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa65
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, xenial, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash nomodeset ---
ls: cannot access '/home/usr/.config': No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:


=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="2018-02-28-19-15-18-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="550f2a26" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="550f2a26-01"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="B51F-26E1" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="550f2a26-02"


=================== efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,17d38a63-10e3-4fb6-bf42-105e39e341e5,0x800,0x145000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,17d38a63-10e3-4fb6-bf42-105e39e341e5,0x800,0x145000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0002* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)/CDROM(1,0x2fe36c,0x4a00)..BO
Boot0003* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP, Partition 2   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x38,0x2fe36c,0x1280)..BO

=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:



=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE    SIZE LABEL
loop0 loop squashfs  1.5G
sda   disk iso9660  14.4G Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS amd64
sda2  part vfat      2.3M Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS amd64
sda1  part iso9660   1.5G Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS amd64

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs
sda      1  0  1 running /cdrom
sda2     1  0  1
sda1     1  0  1


=================== mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8011324k,nr_inodes=2002831,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1605812k,mode=755)
/dev/sda on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=4c8e8751f85d58b2)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18649)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1605812k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  acpi_thermal_rel autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk ecryptfs fb0 fd freefall full fuse gpiochip0 hidraw0 hpet hugepages hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 initctl input kmsg kvm lightnvm log mapper mcelog media0 mem memory_bandwidth mqueue net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 serial sg0 shm snapshot snd stderr stdin stdout tpm0 tpmrm0 uhid uinput urandom userio v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net vhost-vsock video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda       iso9660   1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
aufs           aufs      7.7G   57M  7.7G   1% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G  184K  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G  300K  7.7G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   92K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999

=================== fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1564921856 bytes, 3056488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.4 GiB, 15502147584 bytes, 30277632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x550f2a26

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0 3172287 3172288  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       3138412 3143147    4736  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Error: no partitions
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.


=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  repair-filesystems


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix this? Thanks in advance and let me know if more information is required.

Comment: It is only seeing the USB drive you booted to.  There is no hard drives listed here.   Did you change anything in the system BIOS during this process?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your laptop is using NVMe storage, so the drives and partition should have nvme prefix, not sd. On my NVMe laptop drive it looks like this:

```
ls -la /dev/nvme0*
crw------- 1 root root 242, 0 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 2 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1p2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 3 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1p3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 4 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1p4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 5 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1p5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 6 Jun  7 10:27 /dev/nvme0n1p6
```

For my system, the first storage is nvme0n1 and I can still can use fdisk to configure it.

```
sudo fdisk /dev/nvme0n1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296 1678288895 1677721600   800G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1945931776 1998360575   52428800    25G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1998360576 2000408575    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1678288896 1945931775  267642880 127.6G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Command (m for help):
```

PS: @Terrance is right, sda you see is your usb boot drive.